# How to show image in teaser of any content

Tags: views, users, nodes

I have created a view which displays the recent blog entries made by users...i have placed this block in sidebar...right now the view is displaying only the recent content with the teaser..however i need the view to display the recent content along with the user picture who posted it and display any image in the teaser if the user has also posted an image in the blog...i.e., if there is an image in the blog then it should be displayed in the view and if not then the teaser should be displayed

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not very clear but :

1. To display **user's picture**, add "author of the node" relationship to the view and "user picture" field, *with* the relationship.
2. To display **post's picture**, presuming it's in a distinct image field and not in the body, go to your *display settings* of your content type, in the *teaser* section, set the image as you want it to be displayed, it will then appear in your view.

Comment: thanks...i am able to display the post's picture..however not the user picture..have added the field and also the relationship but no result

Comment: Oh because it's my fault, if you use *teaser* display type in your view, you can't add fields, even this one. You have to get all your view to use fields instead of teaser.

Comment: yes..i was able to understand that...but if i use fields then how do i show the teaser then?

Comment: You have to include all fields used in *teaser display*... And for the body, it will ask you which build mode to use, select teaser

Comment: thanks a million...thank you so much...if i could i would have voted the answer up...thanks again